# Not able to create the new instance while spring boot application is shutting down

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, reactive-programming

I am using reactive library for Elastic Search Bulk processor for bulk indexing. My spring boot application is shutting down in some scenarios, but before shutting down completely, bulk processor is trying to complete the ongoing bulk indexing job. It is not able to create an instance of a class which is required to complete the bulk processor indexing job. Getting following exception:

`"stack_trace":"org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'droppedEventsReporter': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:220)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:233)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1284)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1245)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:494)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:349)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)\n\tat`

It will be very helpful if someone can suggest any solution.

I tried to create new instance using @autowired and using new keyword both but none of them worked.